# How to get base image in upsells in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento

I would like to show the base image in upsells, not the thumbnail or the small image but the image.

I have tried: 
`<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'image')->resize(118,82) ?>`

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use basic function like

```
<?php

echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
       ->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage() ); //getSmallImage(), getThumbnail()

?>
```

hope this will work for you.